# Spring data specify datasource for repository

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data

I have a few spring data repositories for redis.
We are in middle of transition to new redis server. To make it smooth, I need to write data to the old and new redises simultaneously.
So I need to have two sets of CRUD repositories in runtime, each of them should use different datasource (redis template).
I've found an example to introduce a few datasources in Spring app, and use JPA.
But I was wondering if it's possible to specify a datasource for the Spring data repository.
Thanks!